# Advanced SQL query on wordpress filter by category and custom field

Tags: mysql, wordpress, custom-fields

I want to select the distinct value of a custom field "`portata`" filtered by category and an other custom field.

This is the query to select a custom value by category:

```
global $wpdb;
$querystr2 = "
SELECT DISTINCT wpostmeta.meta_value 
FROM $wpdb->posts wposts
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta ON wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id 
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON (wposts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)


WHERE wpostmeta.meta_key = 'portata'
AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id IN($variabile_c)
ORDER BY wpostmeta.meta_value ASC

";
```

How can I add on other custom field to the filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to join against $wpdb->postmeta again, using a separate alias for each join, and add a couple of ANDs to the WHERE clause in order to apply the extra condition -- something like:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT wpostmeta1.meta_value
   FROM $wpdb->posts wposts
     LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta1 ON wposts.ID = wpostmeta1.post_id 
     LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta2 ON wposts.ID = wpostmeta2.post_id 
     LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON (wposts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
     LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
   WHERE wpostmeta1.meta_key = 'portata'
     AND wpostmeta2.meta_key = 'other-custom-field-value'
     AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
     AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id IN($variabile_c)
   ORDER BY wpostmeta1.meta_value ASC
```

replacing 'other-custom-field-value' with the second custom field value on which you need to filter.

Comment: Glad to be of help, and I'd appreciate it if you'd accept my answer so that I get the reputation benefit for it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Aaron Miller!now it works!

```
SELECT DISTINCT wpostmeta1.meta_value
FROM $wpdb->posts wposts
     LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta1 ON wposts.ID = wpostmeta1.post_id 
     LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta2 ON wposts.ID = wpostmeta2.post_id 
     LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON (wposts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
     LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
WHERE wpostmeta1.meta_key = 'portata'
     AND wpostmeta2.meta_key = 'alimentazione'
AND wpostmeta2.meta_value = '$variabile_portata'
     AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
     AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id IN($variabile_c)
ORDER BY wpostmeta1.meta_value ASC
```

Thanks Aaron Miller.
Now if you I want 1 other filer by custom field I have to add 1 left join?
thanks!

Comment: You'll need to join against $wpdb->postmeta once per custom field filter, using a unique alias in each join -- the aliases here are wpostmeta1 and wpostmeta2, so you might add for example wpostmeta3, &c. Keep an eye on your performance, though -- adding multiple left joins tends to produce a very large result set for the database engine to filter, which can take a while if your indexes aren't in good shape or if you have a lot of custom fields defined.